# Prove that $\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n+1}$ is an integer.

Tags: combinatorics, integers, catalan-numbers

Prove that $\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n+1}$ is an integer.

I know a method using algebraic manipulation to prove this statement but can anyone tell me (even a slight hint would do) how to prove this using a combinatorial argument?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Proof_of_the_formula

Comment: These are the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), so there should be an abundance of proofs to find once their name is known.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/catalan-numbers/5441FB5B09E9C01185834D9CBB9DFAD9

Answer (score 3):

At stated in the comments, these are the Catalan numbers. On the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), some combinatorial interpretations are given. My favourite proof is to solve [Bertrand's ballot problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) and to use it to find a formula for the Catalan recurrence. This method is presented on p.13 of [Four Proofs of the Ballot Theorem by Renault](https://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Ereiner/Classes/Four_Proofs_of_Ballot_Theorem.pdf).

If you look up [Richard Stanley](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/), you'll find that the fellow has been collecting for years combinatorial problems whose solution is the Catalan numbers. He is famous, among other reasons, for having [dozens of exercises](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/ec/catalan.pdf) that boil down to the Catalan numbers in his book, Enumerative Combinatorics. In the end in 2015, he published a book on it, [Catalan Numbers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107427746), which has over 200 objects that can be counted using the Catalan numbers. On this [web page](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/ec/), he wrote that

> The material I have gathered on Catalan numbers was collected into a monograph. This will be the final version of my material on Catalan numbers. The current web page will not be updated.